# I paid visa fees for F4 derivative child and filled DS-260 with documents.I was rejected for aging out per CSPA. What shall I do next?

Tags: usa, greencard, refusal

May I ask about CSPA for immigration process for I-130 F4 and is it possible to redeem for aging out child under CSPA law?

We are in trouble and please help us and give any advices.

Q: May I ask about whether I am still eligible for CSPA or not? Please suggest me and give advices what shall we do next.

My aunt filed I-130 for my mom in Burma since May 2006 and got receipt letter from USCIS on round about May 2006.

Didn't get any notification or letter from USCIS that my case has been accepted till this year NVC letter even My aunt regularly changed her address changing to USCIS.

ME,YOUNGEST SON IN FAMILY, is 21st August 1993 born, unmarried and I was over 12 years while my aunt filed I-130 for my mom.

We got NVC letter on this April 19th 2019 to process with CEAC account.

My name was listed in the derivative applicant list and they demanded to pay visa fees and filled out DS-260 and got confirmation letter and we did fill civil documents after that in the middle of 2019 May.

We waited NVC to review our case and they suddenly removed my name from the list yesterday  and we added my name again and

they send a message "ADD APPLICANT IS NOT ELIGIBLE DERIVATIVE, OVER 21 YEARS PER CSPA" !!!.

In CEAC, even my elderest Brother who is gonna turn 32, 1987 born, name was listed in the derivative applicant list.We intentionally removed elderest nephew and niece from the name list for being not able to immigrate because they are married before that event occur.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/17439/f4-cspa-name-missing-in-interview-letter

Comment: You think you qualify under CSPA. The NVC say you don't. It matters little what some bloke on the internet thinks. You can contest this yourself: make your case and ask the NVC why they disagree. Ultimately, though, you probably need to consult a lawyer.